# EXTJS4 - Modified records not showing up

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid that has CellEditing enabled and when I click "Save" I want to capture everything the user has changed.

I tried using `getUpdatedRecords` and `getModifiedRecords` and neither are populating correctly.

How do I properly implement these methods?

**Code**

```
...
    saveGrid: function () {
            var controller = this,
                accManagerStore = Ext.getStore('Management'),
                modifiedRecords = (accManagerStore && accManagerStore.getUpdatedRecords()),
                modifiedRecords2 = (accManagerStore && accManagerStore.getModifiedRecords()),
                testDataWindow = controller.view,
                activeRec = controller.activeRecord,
                assetId = (activeRec && activeRec.get('assetId')),

                resultsArray = [];

            this.getAccountManagementGrid().getStore().sync();


        },...
```

**Console**

```
modifiedRecords: []
​​
length: 0
​​
__proto__: []
​
modifiedRecords2: []
​​
length: 0
```

Comment: It's been a while, but I think you have to say UpdateRecord to get the change pushed back to your record from your form.

Answer (score 0):

...
    `saveGrid: function () {
            var controller = this,
                accManagerStore = Ext.getStore('Management'),
                accManagerStore.sync()`

That should work.The purpose of a framework is to make your work easier not harder that said Calling the sync method should thus get the updated record and pass it to your proxy which will then handle the updated data